# Realm Android query a list of primitives not working

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

Two objects:
A parent and a child with a list of parent id.

**Parent**

```
open class Parent(
        @PrimaryKey
        open var id: Long? = null
) : RealmObject() {}
```

**Child**

```
open class Child(
        @PrimaryKey
        open var id: Long? = null,
        open var parentsId: RealmList<Long>? = null
) : RealmObject() {}
```

Can't find a way to obtain the list of child with a parent id.

I tried this because of this [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361):

```
realm.where(Child::class.java).equalTo("parentsId", idParent).findAll()
```

But it's not working, always getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'parentsId' in class 'Child' is of invalid type 'INTEGER_LIST'.
```

Comment: `Enhancements: RealmList can now contain String, byte[], Boolean, Long, Integer, Short, Byte, Double, Float and Date values. Queries and Importing primitive lists from JSON are not supported yet.` so **Queries primitive lists is not supported yet** see [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#enhancements-4), it is tracked at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361 and currently *Blocked*.

Comment: Ah ok... Sheeeeeeeeeeeeet. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I agree, I want to see `RealmString` and `RealmLong` removed from all code bases, but primitive lists can't query like this yet unfortunately

Comment: Can't you set up a link from the Child to the Parent, or the Parent to the Child; and then set up a linking objects in the opposing direction when you save your models?

Comment: Yes I can and I will. Don't have the choice..

Comment: That's how I used to do it, except back then I couldn't even use `@LinkingObjects` which is a shame because it is super-powerful. Also Realm 3.x+ doesn't really like manually bidirectional schemas anymore anyways.